# is there a simpler method for doing this job?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define STR(x) #x
#define STR2(x) STR(x)
#define LINE_FILE ("Line " STR2(__LINE__) " of file " STR2(__FILE__))

int main(void)
{
    const char *str = LINE_FILE;

    printf("%s\n", str);

    return 0;
}
```

Is this the only definition scheme that will make STR(x) to print the actual **LINE** and **FILE**???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
STR2(__FILE__)
```

`__FILE__` is already a string literal:  you don't need to use `STR2` here.

You should also probably remove the parentheses from the macro so that it can be concatenated with other string literals, if you wanted to do that:

```
#define LINE_FILE "Line " STR2(__LINE__) " of file " __FILE__
```

Comment: thanks a lot! but what about STR2(__LINE__)? Is this the only way to print the line number using definitions?

Comment: @garihull:  It's the only way to convert the line number into a string literal, yes. `__LINE__` is an integer value, not a string.

Answer (score 4):

`printf("Line %d of file  %s\n", __LINE__,__FILE__);`

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but maybe someone can make one out of it.
You can concatenate not only strings in a macro by using "##"

But this does not work:

```
#define LINE_FILE "Line " ## (__LINE__) ## " of file " __FILE__
```

rest of the #define is taken from James McNellis